# Why My two dimencional array/ Matric it's printed wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Why is not printed like a matrice? (I mean side by side.)
*Dont really know if there is a difference between two dimencional arrays and matrices as i can understand it seems there are the same thing to me.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){

    int array[][] = {{4,5,6},
                     {6,8,9}};

    int array1[][] = {{5,4,6},
                     {5,6,7}};
```

Declaring how many rows and colons  my first array has.

```
    System.out.println("Number of rows = " +array.length);
    System.out.println("Number of cols = " + array[0].length);
```

Printing  the array.

```
    int l = array.length;
    int c = array[0].length;

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Print matrice : \n " );
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<c; j++){

        System.out.println(" | " +array[i][j]+ " | ");
    }
     System.out.println(" \n");
    }


}
}
```

Printing result :

```
Number of rows = 2
Number of cols = 3

Print matrice : 

 | 4 | 
 | 5 | 
 | 6 | 


 | 6 | 
 | 8 | 
 | 9 |
```

Comment: try changing your `println` calls to `print`.

Comment: That was fast , thanks man it really worked

Comment: Happy to help. I recommend you choose an answer below that you think explains the cause and solution best, and check it off as the accepted solution.

Comment: @Zircon I checked yours and it worked but why you comment and didn't give me the anwer directly below doesn't that give you more points or reputation?

Comment: Sure, but I don't really find this solution especially useful for the site. Besides, if I made it an answer, I would have explained the problem and why the solution works as Keiwan did, and it would have taken just as long to write it, if not longer. Answering questions should not be a race here, but that's what a lot of questions like this one turn out to be. By making a quick comment that works, others are no longer pressured to write quick, poor-quality answers to get the points the quickest. That's why a good answer like Keiwan's came to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println` automatically adds a line break. You could change both of your `print` statements to `System.out.print`, or change it to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<c; j++){
        System.out.print(" | " +array[i][j]+ " | ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

`System.out.println()` will add the line-break without the need of the additional `\n`. (Note that this is also the reason why you are getting two line-breaks between your matrix rows).

Comment: to nitpick, `System.out.println();` will already do the newline (and save a few method calls)

Comment: Oh, you mean leave an empty line.. yes, that's right. Hm, I guess the OP doesn't want that either..

Comment: I think you're confused as to what I meant, your two methods have the same result in the console.  I meant this, `System.out.println();` calls the `println()` method (no paramater!) which only calls the `newLine()` method...

Comment: However, `System.out.println("");` calls the `println(String s)` method, which also calls the `newLine()` method, but after calling the `print(String s)` method, which calls the `write(String s)` method, which calls `ensureOpen()`, `write(s)`, `flushBuffer()`, `flush()` ... that's a lot of method calls for an empty string.  In short, `println()` will have the same result in the console as `println("")` but get there quicker :)

Comment: Oh, you were referring to my very first version, that makes sense. I got a bit confused because I had already changed it from `println("")` to `println()` before you made the comment.

Comment: Ha, we got a ConcurrentModificationException ;-)  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
System.out.println(" | " +array[i][j]+ " | ");
```

to

```
System.out.print(" | " + array[i][j] + " | ");
```

System.out.println() jumps to the next line after printing thus making the next element to appear below.